# What is the weather like at Glacier National Park in late June / early July?

Tags: usa, weather-and-climate

My friends and I are planning a road trip to Glacier National Park this summer.  We'll arrive at the park June 29th and stay for four days.

Comment: http://www.nps.gov/glac/planyourvisit/weather.htm

Answer (score 2):

You'd be looking at [an average day of lows around 48F/8C and highs around 80F/27C](http://www.weather.com/weather/wxclimatology/monthly/graph/AKGLBA:13).  However the weather is changeable, it can snow even in June (though unlikely) and [you've got about a 40% chance of rain](http://www.nps.gov/glac/planyourvisit/weather.htm).